# MySQL Like query not recognising anything but first word in database

Tags: php, mysql, string, sql-like

Basically I am trying to use a `$gen` variable to match a user query to a string stored in a database describing a genre of music. My problem is that if the genre is Indie/Pop and the user selects Indie as a search query the event will display. If they select Pop the event does not display.

Here is how i am querying the database.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tab WHERE genre LIKE '$gen%'AND dateForm = '$datepicker'";
```

Any help appreciated as ever

php script to get info

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','python');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax");
$gen = $_GET['gen'];
$gen = mysql_real_escape_string($gen);
$tab = $_GET['tab'];
$tab = mysql_real_escape_string($tab);
$datepicker = $_GET['datepicker'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tab WHERE genre LIKE '%$gen%' AND dateForm = '$datepicker'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table class='table table-hover'><thead>
<tr>
<th><h3>Artist</th>
<th><h3>Location</th>
<th><h3>Date</th>
<th><h3>Genre</th>
<th><h3>Preview</th>
</tr></thead>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {    
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['artist'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td> <b>Venue: </b>" . $row['venue'] . "<p><b>Location: </b>" . $row['location'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['datez'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['genre'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . '<iframe width="100%" height="100" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/' . $row['link'] . '&amp;color=000000&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>' . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
 }  

echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
```

The gen variable is made using AJAX

```
  function ajaxFunction(){
  var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

  try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } catch (e){
  // Internet Explorer Browsers
  try{
      ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  }catch (e) {
    try{
      ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e){
      // Something went wrong
      alert("Your browser broke!");
      return false;
      }
    }
  }

  // Create a function that will receive data 
  // sent from the server and will update
  // div section in the same page.
  ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
      var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
      ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }
  }

  // Now get the value from user and pass it to
  // server script.
  var gen = document.getElementById('gen').value;
  var datepicker = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
  var tab = document.getElementById('tab').value;
  //var datepicker = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
  var queryString = "?gen=" + gen ;
  queryString += "&datepicker=" + datepicker +"&tab=" + tab;
  ajaxRequest.open("GET", "getuser.php" + 
                              queryString, true);
  ajaxRequest.send(null); 

  }
```

Comment: Put the `%` on both sides obviously. `x%` only matches x followed by whatever.

Comment: Using double % is the correct way like above comments and it would be more efficient if you use your haystack and needle with all lower or upper case searches.

Comment: Echo $sql is it as expected? This code looks like it'd open you to injections.

Comment: Mixing mysql_real_escape_string and mysqli, huh?  Look at using prepared statements with mysqli, not escape strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, some security lessons in here.  Bind the parameters *$gen* (with the wildcards added) and *$datepicker* in the prepared query.  Since you can't bind column or table names, I'd run something like I did below with *$tab* and the allowed *$tables* array.  This allows you to set a predefined list of tables that the query is allowed to run against and will throw an exception if the table provided is not in the list.

I don't like mysqli or procedural code so I don't use it much but I'm pretty sure everything is in order.

```
mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax");
// Add wildcards here
$gen = '%'.$_GET['gen'].'%';
$tab = $_GET['tab'];
$datepicker = $_GET['datepicker'];

// Check if $tab is in allowed tables (array $tables)
$tables = ['valid_table1', 'valid_table2', 'valid_table3'];
if (!in_array($tab, $tables)) {
    throw new Exception('Hey, get outta here!');
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tab WHERE genre LIKE ? AND dateForm = ?";
// Prepare, bind, and execute
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,$sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $gen, $datepicker);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I'll have a study using prepared statements. First tim using PHP ;)

Comment: Yes, look at the examples here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php.  You're using procedural code, so you can skip down to that.  Using prepared statements is the safest (and most efficient) way to protect against injections.

Comment: really appreciate that mate.

Comment: @DanielParkin Since you are new to PHP, make sure the read http://www.phptherightway.com/ to avoid a lot of common mistakes, and so save you a lot of time in having to unlearn things later.

Comment: @DanielParkin, you could look into OOP (object oriented programming) and then look into using PDO (which replaces mysqli and also works for other DBMS).  I personally like PDO more and think it offers several advantages but it does not have procedural methods like mysqli so it requires objects.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a % at the beginning of the search value

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tab WHERE genre LIKE '%$gen%'AND dateForm = '$datepicker'";
```

Comment: I have tried that and it doesnt work. Im wondering if its because there is no space between the two words? They literally are in the database like Indie/Pop

Comment: Can you post 1) the actual query generated, 2) your schema and 3) some sample data?  A space not being between the words should not cause the query to fail...